# lodash - traverse object and convert/append children as array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to find the best approach with `lodash` to traverse (deep walk) an object and convert any encountered child object to an `array` and append it.

Given this object:

```
   let testObj = {
    'name': 'testdata',
    'active': false,
    'nestedData': {
        0: {
            0: { 'name': '1', 'value': 1 },
            1: { 'name': '2', 'value': 1 },
            2: { 'name': '3', 'value': 1 },
            3: { 'name': '4', 'value': 1 },
        },
        1: {
            0: { 'name': '5', 'value': 1 },
            1: { 'name': '6', 'value': 1 },
            2: { 'name': '7', 'value': 1 },
            3: { 'name': '8', 'value': 1 },
        },
    },
    'moreData': {
        '0': { 'name': 'test1', 'value': 1 },
        '1': { 'name': 'test2', 'value': 2 },
        '2': { 'name': 'test3', 'value': 3 },
        '3': { 'name': 'test4', 'value': 4 },
    },
    moreData2: {
        '0': {
            'name': 'test1',
            'arr': ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'],
            'value': false,
        },
        '1': {
            'name': 'test2',
            'arr': ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'],
            'value': true,
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best approach to append the children as an array to the object, like this:

```
   let testObjResult = {
    'name': 'testdata',
    'active': false,
    'nestedData': {
        0: {
            0: { 'name': '1', 'value': 1 },
            1: { 'name': '2', 'value': 1 },
            2: { 'name': '3', 'value': 1 },
            3: { 'name': '4', 'value': 1 },
        },
        1: {
            0: { 'name': '5', 'value': 1 },
            1: { 'name': '6', 'value': 1 },
            2: { 'name': '7', 'value': 1 },
            3: { 'name': '8', 'value': 1 },
        },
    },
    'nestedDataArray': [
        [
            { 'name': '1', 'value': 1 },
            { 'name': '2', 'value': 1 },
            { 'name': '3', 'value': 1 },
            { 'name': '4', 'value': 1 },
        ],
        [
            { 'name': '5', 'value': 1 },
            { 'name': '6', 'value': 1 },
            { 'name': '7', 'value': 1 },
            { 'name': '8', 'value': 1 },
        ],
    ],
    'moreData': {
        '0': { 'name': 'test1', 'value': 1 },
        '1': { 'name': 'test2', 'value': 2 },
        '2': { 'name': 'test3', 'value': 3 },
        '3': { 'name': 'test4', 'value': 4 },
    },
    'moreDataArray': [
        { key: '0', 'name': 'test1', 'value': 1 },
        { key: '1', 'name': 'test2', 'value': 2 },
        { key: '2', 'name': 'test3', 'value': 3 },
        { key: '3', 'name': 'test4', 'value': 4 },
    ],
    moreData2: {
        '0': {
            'name': 'test1',
            'arr': ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'],
            'value': false,
        },
        '1': {
            'name': 'test2',
            'arr': ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'],
            'value': true,
        }
    },
    moreData2Array: [
        {
            'key': '0',
            'name': 'test1',
            'arr': ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'],
            'value': false,
        },
        {
            'key': '1',
            'name': 'test2',
            'arr': ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'],
            'value': true,
        }
    ]
}
```

The new array name/key would be same as original object but appended 'Array'. Would be nice to also have the option of keeping the object key when converting to an array as above.

I've experimented with recursively calling `_.mapValues` `_.mapKeys` with `_.toArray` but doesn't work. Maybe using `_.transform` somehow? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `nestedDataArray` doesn't have `key` values. Is this intentional?

Comment: Hi, yes. was just to show would be nice to have optional key's in the generated array's..

Comment: I'm curious as to your use case. Seems to me you'd only be doubling the size of your object, without gaining anything. By using integers as keys you need to use bracket notation (as if it was an array) to access it's properties anyways (`testObj.nestedData[0][0].name`)